# Navigate from popoverPresentationController to new ViewController

Tags: ios, swift3, uipopovercontroller

I have two viewCcontroller's, FirstViewController and SecondViewController. Now I am showing a popoverpresentationcontroller in FirstViewController which has a button a several textFields which takes imput from the user. Now once the button is clicked I want to navigate it to SecondViewController and pass the data along.But I am not able to navigate to second view controller . If I use segue from popoverpresentationcontroller's button to SecondViewController it navigates successfully, but I want to achieve this programmatically. Any help on how to do this??

This is my button click code

```
@IBAction func goTo(_ sender: UIButton) {

  let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
  let destination = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
            destination.flag = flag
             sender: sender)


        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant navigate since there is no `navigation controller` on presented view controller

So you first have to add `navigation controller` and then you can perform navigation.

```
let nav1 = UINavigationController()
nav1.viewControllers = [self]
nav1.pushViewController(child, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just clean your code a bit.

```
@IBAction func goTo(_ sender: UIButton) {    
    let destinationViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    destinationViewController.flag = flag
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true)
}
```

> Please also note to setup the viewController in the Main.storyboard

[image]